# How to get id_user (primary key ()) in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I want to insert two rows into master and detail table.

Master and detail table with autoincremented id.

```
CREATE TABLE MI_User (
    id_user NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    age NUMBER(3),
    name_user varchar2(128),
    constraint USER_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_user));

CREATE TABLE Friends (
    id_friend NUMBER(11) not null,
    name VARCHAR2(64),
        id_user NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    constraint FRIEND_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_friend)
);
```

Model classes are:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Friend> friends;
}

public class Friend {
    private Long id_user;
    private String name;
}
```

There is example from Hibernate:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
User user = new User(name, age);
employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
tx.commit();
```

I try to insert with JDBS:

```
conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hr", "hr");
            ps = conn
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MI_USER (BALANCE, AGE, NAME_USER, GENDER, COMPANY, EMAIL, ADDRESS)\n" +
                            "    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setDouble(1, user.getDoubleBallans());
            ps.setInt(2, user.getAge());
            ps.setString(3, user.getName());
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

How to get id_user and insert row into detail table?

Comment: Are you interested in the JDBC or the Hibernate answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ps.getGeneratedKeys()` method and send `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as second parameter in `conn.prepareStatement()` method.

Comment: Also the linked question doesn't answer it for Oracle, because there are some extra gotcha's when doing this on Oracle, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136223/java-jdbc-primary-key-oracle-database

Comment: Your current answer is slightly better, but not actually correct for Oracle, see the link in my previous comment.